# Possible to build dependency with different flags for executable and tests?

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

Is it possible to build our executables and tests with differently flagged versions of a dependency?

We'd like to run our tests having `vector +UnsafeChecks` to make sure any out of bounds access fails the tests but have executables built against `vector -UnsafeChecks` so that it doesn't have to pay the performance penalties.

Currently using stack but happy to here what cabal solutions there may be too.

Comment: You can `cabal test --constraint="vector +UnsafeChecks"`, would it work for you?

Comment: Thanks - that certainly does the trick for `cabal`!